# Hashcat / John the Ripper - find password when you know most of password but don't remember the sequence

Tags: passwords, hashcat

Here is a scenario i have password protext a folder containing pictures with 7z and i forgot the password, the encryption type is AES-256. i remember most of the words used in password.

1: All the words in password were seperated by underscore.

2: The password contain these 2 words for sure seperated with "_" but i don't remember the sequence.

AB12, 02-May-2021

3: I'm not sure about these but i think i used the following as well, seperated with "_".

Password, Picture, Pictures

In my mind password was something like following pattern.

AB12_02-May-2021_Picture_Password

OR

AB12_02-May-2021_Pictures_Password

OR

AB12_02-May-2021_Password

OR

02-May-2021_AB12_Pictures_Password

OR

02-May-2021_AB12_Picture_Password

OR

02-May-2021_AB12_Password

How can i guess the password using Hashcat or John the Ripper, any help in the right direction is appreciated.